# SharePoint search refiners only needed on a certain content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, enterprise-search

All,

I have a bunch of documnets in a content type, across 2 site collections. I have specific refiners in the search which their crawled propeties are assigned to a managed property which is on the refiners.

Now the refiners work OK, but if you search for anything outside of the bunch of documents the refiners are wrong. So if you search for a keyword which is not a part of the documnets the newly created refiners do not giver accurate info.

Firstly I dont know why that is, surely the refiners should be hidden instead. 
Can i show / hide some refiners on the web part according to the content type of the document crawled ?

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, the requirement to hide a search refiners based on the content type of the document cannot be completed.

You can only choose to hide all search refiners.

[Hide Available Refiners in SharePoint search refinement panel](http://blog.binarybits.net/programming/sharepoint/hide-available-refiners-in-sharepoint-search-refinement-panel/)